# Show $ \Lambda $ is a field, but not a $\sigma$-field.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega=\mathbb N$,  the integers. Define:
$$
\Lambda  = \{ A \subset \mathbb N: A\quad \text{or} \quad{A^c}\quad \text{is finite}\}.
$$

Show $\Lambda$ is a field, but not a $\sigma$-field.

I know the difference between  field and $\sigma$-field. But I'm not understanding how to demonstrate.

Comment: What are u not understanding

Comment: Is $\Lambda$ closed under countable unions?

Comment: mathworker21, I don't know how to show it.

Comment: Kenny Wong, I just have this information. But, it is a field, so it's should be closed under countable unions finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not closed under countable unions. Let $\mathbb{E}$ be the even numbers. Then $\mathbb{E} = \bigcup_{ a \in \mathbb{E}} \{a\}$ where each $\{a\} \in \Lambda$. Clearly, $\mathbb{E}$ is not finite and it's compliment is not finite, so $\mathbb{E} \not \in \Lambda$.